# Кодировка имён в базе

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка, facebook, facebook-api

Добрый вечер.

Столкнулся с небольшой проблемкой, сделал регистрацию юзеров через фейсбук и имя полученное оттуда пишу в базу. С английскими именами всё в порядке, но там оказывается есть и имена других национальностей. Проблемы начались уже даже начиная с русских имён. И как ни странно фейсбук никак не переводит их, а так и оставляет. Может быть можно как-то вытащить английское написание имени? - я незнаю.

Страшно представить что будет если вписать тайский/китайский...
В общем, сайт глобальный, и в базу может попасть юзер с любым именем.  Так что хотел узнать существует ли какая-то кодировка, которая без проблем писала бы в базу всё это дело?
или тут нужно идти другим путём, проверяя англиское имя или нет, и если нет - предложить вписать имя на английском? - не семый удобный вариант

И.. почему русские-то имена не захотели работать?) насколько я знаю фейсбук присылает всё в utf-8? поле у меня стоит varchar со стандартной кодировкой utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала необходимо узнать, в какой кодировке приходит, затем соответвенно конвертировать в utf8, с mysql тоже есть некоторые особенности, наиболее понятно описано здесь: [Кодировки в MySQL](http://www.anton-pribora.ru/articles/mysql/mysql-charsets/)

Comment: Ага, спасибо.  
Будем разбираться.

Comment: И все-таки в статье говорится только про русский язык, а как же быть с остальными?

Comment: @Denis Masster перед utf8 все равны )

Answer (score 1):

Ставь кодировку UTF-8 на ВСЁ (от БД до файлов) и будет тебе счастье (независимо от языка)